# Increasing client packet in kernel recv-q (confirm with netstat) and not reading packet

Tags: netty, recv

I don't know it is netty 3.2.7.Final bugs. The problem is that unexpectedly at client-side (using SecureChatClient), increasing packet in recv-q that received real-time messages from server-side (using SecureChatServer).
I guess that deadlock in reading packets on application-level.

Is it a bugs of netty 3.2.7? or do you have any idea of recv-q increasing?
I've attached the netstat result and jstack thread dump below.

```
Netstat Result : 

tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:54190  server-side'IP-1:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:53254  server-side'IP-2:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:60469  server-side'IP-3:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:35387  server-side'IP-4:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:56935  server-side'IP-5:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:50508  server-side'IP-6:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp 708131 0 client-side'IP:48940  server-side'IP-7:61617  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:50279  server-side'IP-8:61617  ESTABLISHED


tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:53568  server-side'IP-1:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:52674  server-side'IP-2:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:60489  server-side'IP-3:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:48712  server-side'IP-4:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:55519  server-side'IP-5:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:38608  server-side'IP-6:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:57940  server-side'IP-7:61616  ESTABLISHED
tcp     0  0 client-side'IP:51759  server-side'IP-8:61616  ESTABLISHED

Jstack Dump : 

2013-01-11 14:36:20
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode):

"http-80-6" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2dee800 nid=0x1888 in Object.wait() [0x00000000417bd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0e0b630> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0e0b630> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-443-13" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab599a800 nid=0x1887 in Object.wait() [0x00000000419bf000]
"http-443-12" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e5800 nid=0x1886 in Object.wait() [0x0000000042339000]
"http-443-11" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e4800 nid=0x1885 in Object.wait() [0x000000004253b000]
"http-443-10" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e4000 nid=0x1884 in Object.wait() [0x000000004273d000]
"http-443-9" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e3000 nid=0x1883 in Object.wait() [0x000000004293f000]
"http-443-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e2800 nid=0x1881 in Object.wait() [0x0000000042b41000]
"http-443-7" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43e2000 nid=0x1880 in Object.wait() [0x0000000042d43000]
"http-443-6" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab5aa3800 nid=0x17b7 in Object.wait() [0x0000000042f45000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0e0c2c0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0e0c2c0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab30a4800 nid=0x17b6 in Object.wait() [0x0000000043349000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0e0b780> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0e0b780> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3c4b800 nid=0x17b5 in Object.wait() [0x0000000043147000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0e0ba20> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0e0ba20> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3f26800 nid=0x17b4 in Object.wait() [0x000000004354b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0e0bcc0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0e0bcc0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab30a4000 nid=0x111e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"http-443-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab6017000 nid=0x4af5 in Object.wait() [0x000000004394f000]
"http-443-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab42e6000 nid=0x2f85 in Object.wait() [0x0000000043b51000]
"http-443-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab40a5800 nid=0x632a in Object.wait() [0x0000000043d53000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0dfce70> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0dfce70> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab435a000 nid=0x4139 in Object.wait() [0x000000004556b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031e9a0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000000c031e9a0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ReferenceQueueThread.run(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1122)

"TP-Monitor" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4539800 nid=0x412a in Object.wait() [0x000000004546a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031ea40> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:565)
    - locked <0x00000000c031ea40> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"TP-Processor4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4262000 nid=0x4129 runnable [0x0000000045369000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c031eb00> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.accept(ChannelSocket.java:311)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.acceptConnections(ChannelSocket.java:668)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketAcceptor.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:879)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"TP-Processor3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab43ae000 nid=0x4128 in Object.wait() [0x0000000045268000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031edc8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000c031edc8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"TP-Processor2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab57a6800 nid=0x4127 in Object.wait() [0x0000000045167000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031ee70> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000c031ee70> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"TP-Processor1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab601a000 nid=0x4126 in Object.wait() [0x0000000045066000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031ef18> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked <0x00000000c031ef18> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-443-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab42b7000 nid=0x4125 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044f65000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0167dd8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c0167dd8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-443-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab459a800 nid=0x4124 runnable [0x0000000044e64000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
    - locked <0x00000000eede5038> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    - locked <0x00000000eede50a0> (a com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:735)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:814)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab5fcf000 nid=0x4123 runnable [0x0000000044d63000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c02b1bf0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.acceptSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:178)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3d22000 nid=0x4122 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044c62000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031f6b8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c031f6b8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3d21800 nid=0x4121 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044b61000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c031f918> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00000000c031f918> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-80-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab450d000 nid=0x4120 runnable [0x0000000044a60000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c031fb50> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab45b5800 nid=0x411f waiting on condition [0x0000000041bc1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1631)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab434a800 nid=0x411b waiting on condition [0x000000004495f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)

"scheduler_Worker-9" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab540b000 nid=0x411a in Object.wait() [0x000000004485e000]
"scheduler_Worker-8" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4a22000 nid=0x4119 in Object.wait() [0x000000004475d000]
"scheduler_Worker-7" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4e41000 nid=0x4118 in Object.wait() [0x000000004465c000]
"scheduler_Worker-6" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab577e800 nid=0x4117 in Object.wait() [0x000000004455b000]
"scheduler_Worker-5" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab5096000 nid=0x4116 in Object.wait() [0x000000004445a000]
"scheduler_Worker-4" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab528d800 nid=0x4115 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044359000]
"scheduler_Worker-3" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab5185800 nid=0x4114 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044258000]
"scheduler_Worker-2" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab5185000 nid=0x4113 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044157000]
"scheduler_Worker-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4d8b800 nid=0x4112 in Object.wait() [0x0000000044056000]
"scheduler_Worker-0" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab421f000 nid=0x4111 in Object.wait() [0x0000000043f55000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0536710> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x00000000c0536710> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"New I/O client worker #16-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab80b3000 nid=0x4110 runnable [0x0000000043e54000]
"New I/O client worker #15-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2db1000 nid=0x410e runnable [0x0000000043c52000]
"New I/O client worker #14-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3767000 nid=0x410c runnable [0x0000000043a50000]
"New I/O client worker #13-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab8346800 nid=0x410a runnable [0x000000004384e000]
"New I/O client worker #12-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2874000 nid=0x4108 runnable [0x000000004364c000]
"New I/O client worker #11-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2d08800 nid=0x4106 runnable [0x000000004344a000]
"New I/O client worker #10-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2d71000 nid=0x4104 runnable [0x0000000043248000]
"New I/O client worker #9-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3f2d800 nid=0x4102 runnable [0x0000000043046000]
"New I/O client worker #8-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab3963000 nid=0x4100 runnable [0x0000000042e44000]
"New I/O client worker #7-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab84ee800 nid=0x40fe runnable [0x0000000042c42000]
"New I/O client worker #6-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab312f800 nid=0x40fc runnable [0x0000000042a40000]
"New I/O client worker #5-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab8c08800 nid=0x40fa runnable [0x000000004283e000]
"New I/O client worker #4-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2902000 nid=0x40f8 runnable [0x000000004263c000]
"New I/O client worker #3-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab82bd000 nid=0x40f6 runnable [0x000000004243a000]
"New I/O client worker #2-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab30de800 nid=0x40f4 runnable [0x0000000041ac0000]
"New I/O client worker #1-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab2d28800 nid=0x40f2 runnable [0x00000000418be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:210)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
    - locked <0x00000000c0652130> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000c0652120> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000000c053ebc0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:165)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"pool-2-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab355d000 nid=0x40f0 waiting on condition [0x00000000416bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c03bf0d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab82ff800 nid=0x40ef waiting on condition [0x00000000415bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c034b600> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004118a000 nid=0x40eb in Object.wait() [0x0000000042238000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0018be8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:100)
    - locked <0x00000000c0018be8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab405e800 nid=0x40e9 runnable [0x00000000413b9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c000a428> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:34)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"RMI TCP Accept-9999" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab405b000 nid=0x40e8 runnable [0x00000000412b8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c0018c80> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4001800 nid=0x40e7 runnable [0x0000000040dab000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c0027960> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000041016800 nid=0x40e4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000041014800 nid=0x40e3 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004100e800 nid=0x40e2 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004100c800 nid=0x40e1 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000040feb000 nid=0x40e0 in Object.wait() [0x0000000040b8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0027bf8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000000c0027bf8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000040fe9000 nid=0x40df in Object.wait() [0x0000000040a8d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c0018bd8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000000c0018bd8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040f84800 nid=0x40d9 runnable [0x000000004098c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x00000000c01d29c0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040fe2000 nid=0x40de runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040f97800 nid=0x40da runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040f99000 nid=0x40db runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040f9b000 nid=0x40dc runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040f9d000 nid=0x40dd runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4061000 nid=0x40ea waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1865
```

Comment: You are using a pretty old version of Netty.  How about upgrading with the latest stable version and letting us know your findings?

Comment: I agree to upgrading. but i'm wondering hear from bugs reports about this problem, before upgrading. It's intermittently and i can't reproduce...

Comment: Our process first is sending msg to client(1EA), and clent pass messages on server(8EA with 2 daemon).<br/> Second, each server sends a result message to client.<br/> Third, client delivery the message to another web server.

Comment: The channel option that applied, is only 'keepAlive'. No channel.isWritable, No interestOps and waterMarks... Do you have any idea what's the problem? or What information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Trustin for replying. It was not netty bugs and not in architecturing our service. Also Jstack thread dump is not correct. so sorry about it.

As soon as received message from server-side, the client send a result to 3rd party system (HTTP). Because of a default timeout setting, messaging service hangs out.